# RxSwift - change specific object in PublishSubject on event

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

```
struct Contact : Codable, Hashable {
    var id : String
...
}
```

I use `PublishSubject` to feed the data to the `UITableView`

```
let contacts : PublishSubject<[Contact]> = PublishSubject()
```

And when the value is changed on the other view controller, I want to change the specific value in the array.

I want to change the `Contact` object with the specific id.

```
contacts.filter {$0.id == contactId}[0].someKey = someValue
```

How can I do this with RxSwift?

Answer (score 0):

Understand that a PublishSubject doesn't contain any state so there is nothing in it that you can change. Instead, you emit a new array from the publish subject with a new contact that has the new value.

Somewhere in your code, you are calling `onNext(_:)` on the subject (or connecting it to an Observable that is doing that. We would need to see that code to help you solve your problem.